# reference for webkit sharp not exist in monodevelop

Tags: c#, webkit, monodevelop

ok i create new project with monodevelp and add this code :

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using GtkSharp;
using WebKit;

namespace browserapp
{
    public class browser
    {
        public static void Main () {
            Application.Init ();
            Window window = new Window ("a browser in 12 lines...");
            window.Destroyed += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) {
                Application.Quit ();
            };
            ScrolledWindow scrollWindow = new ScrolledWindow ();
            WebView webView = new WebView ();
            webView.Open ("http://mono-project.com");
            scrollWindow.Add (webView);
            window.Add (scrollWindow);
            window.ShowAll ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }
}
```

and i add all the reference that code need except for :

```
using WebKit;
```

and i search in monodevelop library reference and couldn't find webkit_sharp 
so i searched in Google to find the library and i found this :

https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp

but i couldn't manage how to build it in windows and extract the right dll file for reference so pls if someone can  tell me how to build it in windows and i'm using mono develop the windows version thanks

Comment: Build a Linux box and compile from there. I don't think it is easy enough to build it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the suse rpm here: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Factory/standard/noarch/webkit-sharp-0.3-7.2.noarch.rpm
It's just an archive. You could extract it and pull the dlls out. I'm not sure what you're trying to do would work though.